# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, web-services, json.net

I am implemented one method in my application when it run from visual studio OK fine, but when it run from task scheduler getting this error in Log file

---

System.Exception: Exception occurred in the Sync Process while fetching the suppliers list and method name is GetSuppliers. The Exception is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Line 0, position 0. at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal() at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter, Boolean inArray) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

my method

```
 public string GetSuppliers()
{
    SqlConnection connect = null; var spdb = new Syncdbsource();
    try
    {
        var hsp = new hspservice.MyServiceSoapClient("MyServiceSoap");

        var sdetails = hsp.GetSupplier();
        List<SupplierDetails> supplierslist = null; var countSuppliers = 0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sdetails))
        { supplierslist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SupplierDetails>>(sdetails); }

return countSuppliers + "Inserted";
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25000);

        try
        {
            var output = GetSuppliers();
            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = new Exception(@"Exception occurred in the Sync Process while fetching the suppliers list and method name is GetSuppliers.
                                                   The Exception is " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            var message = exception.Message;
            SendMail.InsertIssue(message.Replace("'", "''"));
            return "-1";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {


        var exception = new Exception(@"Exception occurred in the Sync Process while fetching the suppliers list and method name is GetSuppliers.
                                                   The Exception is " + Environment.NewLine + excp);



        SendMail.InsertIssue(exception.ToString().Replace("'", "''"));

    }
    finally
    {
        if (connect != null && connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        { connect.Dispose(); }

    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Json return string

[{"SUPPLIERID":"10148    ","SUPPLIERNAME":"ALLIED ELECTRONICS - LUD           ","TNAMC":"ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE           ","TNAMB":"                              ","TNAME":"FORT WORTH                    ","TPSTC":"76113-2325","TCSTE":"TX","TCCTY":"USA","PHONE":"616-365-9960   ","FAX":"6163659895     "},{"SUPPLIERID":"10159    ","SUPPLIERNAME":"ALRO STEEL CO.                     ","TNAMC":"P.O. BOX 30382                ","TNAMB":"                              ","TNAME":"LANSING                       ","TPSTC":"48909-7882","TCSTE":"MI","TCCTY":"USA","PHONE":"616-248-7687   ","FAX":"6164522779     "}]

```
public class SupplierDetails
{
    private string _supplierCode;
private string _supplierName;
private string _internalCompanyId;
private string _address1;
private string _address2;
private string _city;
private string _state;
private string _country;
private string _zipCode;
private string _fax;
private string _phone;
public string SUPPLIERID
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_supplierCode) ? _supplierCode : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _supplierCode = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string SUPPLIERNAME
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_supplierName) ? _supplierName : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _supplierName = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string CompanyID
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_internalCompanyId) ? _internalCompanyId : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _internalCompanyId = value.Trim();
    }
}


public string TNAMC
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_address1) ? _address1 : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _address1 = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string TNAMB
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_address2) ? _address2 : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _address2 = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string TNAME
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_city) ? _city : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _city = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string TCSTE
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_state) ? _state : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _state = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string TCCTY
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_country) ? _country : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _country = value.Trim();
    }
}

public string TPSTC
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_zipCode) ? _zipCode : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _zipCode = value.Trim();
    }
}
public string PHONE
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_phone) ? _phone : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _phone = value.Trim();
    }
}
public string FAX
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fax) ? _fax : "-";
    }
    set
    {
        _fax = value.Trim();
    }
}
public SupplierDetails()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for GetSuppliers?  Or what the raw response is?

Comment: Sorry Josh Knack that is third party service method  for fetching Json string we don't have code for that.

Comment: Ok, then can you please post a sample of what is being returned?  Also, the code for SupplierDetails would be helpful.

Comment: and the code for SupplierDetails?

Comment: SupplierDetails is dto Class Only I posted that one also

Answer (score 1):

I put together the simplest implementation of what you presented that I could and found that this works:

```
string sdetails = "[{\"SUPPLIERID\":\"10148 \",\"SUPPLIERNAME\":\"ALLIED ELECTRONICS -LUD \",\"TNAMC\":\"ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE \",\"TNAMB\":\" \",\"TNAME\":\"FORT WORTH \",\"TPSTC\":\"76113 - 2325\",\"TCSTE\":\"TX\",\"TCCTY\":\"USA\",\"PHONE\":\"616 - 365 - 9960 \",\"FAX\":\"6163659895 \"},{\"SUPPLIERID\":\"10159 \",\"SUPPLIERNAME\":\"ALRO STEEL CO. \",\"TNAMC\":\"P.O.BOX 30382 \",\"TNAMB\":\" \",\"TNAME\":\"LANSING \",\"TPSTC\":\"48909 - 7882\",\"TCSTE\":\"MI\",\"TCCTY\":\"USA\",\"PHONE\":\"616 - 248 - 7687 \",\"FAX\":\"6164522779 \"}]";
List<SupplierDetails> supplierslist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SupplierDetails>>(sdetails);
```

Are you sure that the JSON string you have listed in your question is the entire response that you have in `sdetails`?  Given that the error states that you have an error at character 0, I suspect you not receiving the JSON as you described.